# Installing Alfresco with Tomcat 8 on Windows 10

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, alfresco

I am hoping to install Alfresco community edition on my windows 10 machine to help me get familiar with it before implementing it on the server at work (windows server 2012)

I followed their documentation, installed Tomcat 8 , installed PostgreSQL and created a DB called Alfresco with a user also called alfresco. I downloaded the .zip containing the server files for alfresco (WAR files and whatnot) and replaced them in Tomcat's directories.

Started Tomcat service and Postsql's service and entered localhost:8080 but got greeted by this Alfresco page saying "Cannot find Alfresco Repository on this server."

I don't have much experience with servers and databases, am still getting into them but I am kinda clueless where is the problem here.

Cheers!

Comment: Are you trying to get familiar with Alfresco itself, or the installation procedure?

Comment: The installation process in all kinds of environments.

Comment: Any information or error messages on alfresco.log file ?

Comment: @MuralidharanDeenathayalan I have no Alfresco.log file, I installed Alfresco using the .zip distribution and followed the docs to deploy on Tomcat. You want the "Catalina.log"?

Comment: @MuralidharanDeenathayalan ok my bad there is an Alfresco log file, i'll redo the whole installation again and upload the log file if I still have the issue